# Why the terms "GERMAN double fugue", employed twice in Brahms's Ein Deutsches Requiem, and ITALIAN triple fugue (Bach's "St. Anne" p. & fugue)?

Tags: theory, composition

In the Brahms's Ein Deutsches Requiem, the composer sets the words, "Der Gerechten Seelen sind im Gottes Hand, und keine Qual ruhret sie an" as a German double fugue, with 2 completely different fugues being performed simultaneously, one fugue in the chorus and the other in the orchestra.  In the Bach "St. Anne" prelude and fugue, Bach develops each of three fugues separately, then concludes the work with all three fugues performed simultaneously.  Both of these are absolute tour de forces of composition!

Why the assigning of nationalities to the terms double fugue and triple fugue?

Comment: It's not clear what the question is.

Comment: In other words, why the assigning of nationalities to the terms double fugue and triple fugue?

Comment: Who assigned these national names?

Comment: That is EXACTLY my question!

Comment: To echo @Richard, these assignments do not appear in the scores I've looked at.

Comment: However, these terms do occur in music theory texts.

Comment: Your question asks "why", not "who", and if this is coming from music theory texts, then they need to be quoted and cited, because that may provide critical context for the answer. I recommend updated your original post to more specifically reflect your question and its source.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you, man.

Comment: I've never heard these terms before.  Can you give us an example, or better still a few examples, of a theory text that uses them?

Answer (score 5):

From [*Music in the Baroque*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Music_in_the_Baroque_Era_From_Monteverdi/dzV9CgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=german%20double%20fugue%20italian%20triple%20fugue&pg=PT328&printsec=frontcover) by Manfred F. Bukofzer:

> Under Zachow's guidance Handel ... became especially proficient in the Italian type of "double fugue," *i.e.* fugues with counter-subjects which figured prominently in his much-admired improvisations. Like Bach he acquired solid craftsmanship through diligent copying of compositions by German cantors and Italian masters. He copied ... music by Froberger, Kerll, Strungk, Ebner, Johann Krieger, Pachelbel, and others. Significantly, most of these masters belonged to the south German school which depended on Italian style.

I'm talking without much personal expertise or certainty here, but I see a few things in this passage:

- A predilection for double (and presumably triple) fugues was seen as Italianate
- Handel, like Bach and Telemann and many others, demonstrates the "German mixed taste," a cosmopolitan tendency to define "German style" by sampling the styles of Italy and France (and farther afield, like Poland and Turkey).

For more on this notion of "German mixed taste" in the baroque see [*Music for a Mixed Taste: Style, Genre, and Meaning in Telemann's Instrumental Works*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Music_for_a_Mixed_Taste/LXYRDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover) by Steven Zohn. It's also discussed in a book that appears to be a large-scale unpacking of what this outlook meant for the evolving German musical nationalistic self-image over the next few centuries, [*Music and German National Identity*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Music_and_German_National_Identity/roHbXnBqE1wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA46&printsec=frontcover). This book touches, of course, on a piece that puts its "German-ness" right in its title, Brahms' requiem. I'm not enough of a Brahms scholar to know how he felt about any indebtedness to Italian forms, but everyone seems to have some feeling about it, politicizing, de-politicizing, and re-politicizing it, to the point that there's an article titled "How Deutsche a requiem?".

My perception, then, is that, unlike sixth chords, fugues don't come in "Italian" vs "German"; that double and triple fugues, at least in the baroque, were associated with Italian origins; and that the only thing that might make Brahms' one a "German fugue" is that it's part of "a German requiem."

Comment: Thank you for your rather extensive reply with cited sources!  Much appreciated!